# how to delete a parent table that is also a child to it's child?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have two tables both of which reference each other primary keys as foreign keys, I want to drop both but I can't.

I tried this :

```
alter table my_table drop constraint cons_name;
```

That gave me :

ORA-02443: Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please *edit your question* using the `edit` button just below the question tags, and include the DDL for your tables, including all constraints. Without seeing that there's really not much anyone can do to help you. Thanks.

Comment: thanks! sorry for being late as it was exam time and when i posted this post i was very very close to a deadline and couldn't think straight.... very nice community and i hope i can help back later !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following tables (Oracle 12c) ...

```
create table table1 ( column1 primary key )
as
select level
from dual
connect by level <= 10 ;

create table table2 ( column1 primary key )
as
select level
from dual
connect by level <= 10 ;

alter table table1
add constraint fk1 
    foreign key ( column1 ) references table2( column1 ) ;

alter table table2
add constraint fk2 
    foreign key ( column1 ) references table1( column1 ) ;
```

If you want to remove the constraints, make sure that you use the correct
constraint names.

```
-- find the correct constraint names
select table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type
from user_constraints
where table_name in( 'TABLE1', 'TABLE2' ) ;

TABLE_NAME  CONSTRAINT_NAME  CONSTRAINT_TYPE  
TABLE2      SYS_C0021482     P                
TABLE1      SYS_C0021483     P                
TABLE1      FK1              R                
TABLE2      FK2              R  

-- fails: constraint name correct, table name wrong
SQL> alter table table1 drop constraint SYS_C0021482;
ORA-02443: Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint

-- fails: need to disable/remove the FK constraint first
SQL> alter table table1 drop constraint SYS_C0021483;
ORA-02273: this unique/primary key is referenced by some foreign keys

-- okay
SQL> alter table table1 drop constraint FK1 ;
Table TABLE1 altered.
```

If you just want to drop both tables, including all constraints, use ...

```
SQL> drop table table1 cascade constraints purge ;

Table TABLE1 dropped.

SQL> drop table table2 cascade constraints purge ;

Table TABLE2 dropped.
```

Check:

```
-- any constraints left? no.
SQL> select table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type
  2  from user_constraints
  3  where table_name in( 'TABLE1', 'TABLE2' ) ;

no rows selected
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and that worked for me....
i tried to add one constraint and insert values and then add another but that was .... bad!
last query will come handy later!! so thanks for that also !!:D